# What is the name of this 3D shape?

Tags: geometry

I plotted $z = x^2+y^2$ and got this shape. Is there a name for this shape?

How about $z \ge x^2 + y^2$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface is a "circular [paraboloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid)" (a special case of the "elliptic paraboloid"). Slices by planes perpendicular to the $z$ axis are (concentric) circles, while slices by planes parallel to the $z$ axis are (identical) parabolas.

It's an example of a *surface of revolution*, in this case obtained by revolving the basic parabola shape (think $y = x^2$) about its axis.

The filled counterpart would simply be a "solid circular paraboloid".

Answer (score 1):

A paraboloid, see the Wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid

Comment: To be precise, an elliptic paraboloid, I think.